# Program is not reading some characters from first line of text file

Tags: c, file, data-structures

So my program basically asks for the assignment name/student name after clicking "1" from the student menu to submit an assignment. The function reads an arbitrary assignment from a text file I have in my debug folder, called "myassignment.txt". Then it creates a new file called "submission.txt" with the assignment name, student name and the assignment in it.
When I click "2" from the student menu to see the submitted assignment, it prints the assignment name and student name fine, but skips the first few characters from the first line of the actual assignment.
It skips more or less characters depending on how long the assignment name and student name are.
I can't figure out why it's doing this.
Here is my code for the data structure, menu, and functions used in the first two options of the menu:

```
#include "assignmentgrading3.h"

#define MAX_STUDENT_NAME_SIZE 50
#define MAX_ASSIGNMENT_NAME_SIZE 50
#define MAX_ASSIGNMENT_SIZE 1000

typedef struct{
    char assignmentName[MAX_ASSIGNMENT_NAME_SIZE];
    char studentName[MAX_STUDENT_NAME_SIZE];
    char assignment[MAX_ASSIGNMENT_SIZE];
    double score;
} Assignment;

    void studentMenu(Assignment* assignmentStruct) {
        int choice;
        do {
            printf("\nStudent Menu:\n");
            printf("1. Submit an assignment\n");
            printf("2. See the submitted assignment\n");
            printf("3. See the graded assignment\n");
            printf("4. Exit\n");
            printf("Please enter a number from 1 - 4: ");
            scanf("%d", &choice);

            switch (choice) {
                case 1:
                    submitAssignment(assignmentStruct, "myassignment.txt");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    getAssignment(assignmentStruct);
                    displayAssignment(assignmentStruct);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    getGradedAssignment(assignmentStruct);
                    displayGradedAssignment(assignmentStruct);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    exit(0);
                    break;
            }
        } while (choice != 5);
    }

void readRemainingLines(FILE* pFile, char* assignment){
    long charsRead = 0;
    while(fgets(assignment + charsRead, MAX_ASSIGNMENT_SIZE - charsRead, pFile)!= NULL)
    {
        charsRead = strlen(assignment);
        if(charsRead >= MAX_ASSIGNMENT_SIZE - 1)  //Credits: Carl Gelfand
        break;
    }
    assignment[MAX_ASSIGNMENT_SIZE-1] = 0;  //Just to make sure.
}

//Reads the file whose name is provided as string “fileName”, 
//and creates a file named  “submission.txt” as specified in the functional specification. 
//It returns a 1 when it is successful, otherwise it returns a 0. 
int submitAssignment(Assignment* assignmentStruct, char* fileName) {
    FILE* pFile =0;
    //char assignment[MAX_ASSIGNMENT_SIZE];
    char* submissionFileName="submission.txt";

    //Reading information from a user provided file : fileName
    pFile = fopen(fileName,"r");
    if(pFile==NULL){
        printf("%s file did not open\n,",fileName);
        exit(0);
    }//EO if(pFile==NULL)
    printf("Please enter the name of the assignment: ");
    scanf(" %s", assignmentStruct->assignmentName);

    printf("Please enter  your (student) name: ");
    scanf(" %s", assignmentStruct->studentName);
    readRemainingLines(pFile,  assignmentStruct->assignment);
    fclose(pFile);

    // Writing Information to "submission.txt"
    pFile = fopen(submissionFileName, "w");
    if(pFile == NULL) {
        printf("%s file did not open\n,", submissionFileName);
        exit(0);
    } //EO if(pFile==NULL)

    fprintf(pFile, "%s\n", assignmentStruct->assignmentName);
    fprintf(pFile, "%s\n", assignmentStruct->studentName);
    fprintf(pFile, "%s\n", assignmentStruct->assignment);
    fclose(pFile); 
    return 1;
}


int getAssignment(Assignment* assignmentStruct) {
    FILE* pFile = 0;
    pFile = fopen("submission.txt","r");
    if(pFile==NULL){
        printf("file did not open\n,");
        exit(0);
    }
    fscanf(pFile, "%[^\n]", assignmentStruct->assignmentName);
    fscanf(pFile, "%[^\n]", assignmentStruct->studentName);
    readRemainingLines(pFile, assignmentStruct->assignment);
    return 1;
}

void displayAssignment(Assignment* assignmentStruct) {
    char* middleOfAssignment = &(assignmentStruct->assignment[strlen(assignmentStruct->assignmentName) + strlen(assignmentStruct->studentName) + 2]);
    print(assignmentStruct->assignmentName, assignmentStruct->studentName);
    printf("%s \n", middleOfAssignment);
    //printf("%s \n", assignment);
}

void print(char* assignmentName, char* studentName) {
    printf("Assignment Name: %s \nStudent: %s\n", assignmentName, studentName);
}
```

Comment: Too long: didn't read. Have you used a debugger?

Comment: Please try to create a [**Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i'm not gonna waste my time creating an example when i literally have my code right there that has the same problem a fake example would. Thanks though.

Comment: @AlessaFaria What we're asking you to do is shrink the example to something simpler that demonstrates the problem, so we don't have to debug your entire application. If you're having trouble reading the file, we don't need to see the code that writes the file.

Comment: @WeatherVane If i was comfortable enough to use a debugger I wouldn't have posted this question. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: That's wh he emphasized **Minimal**.

Comment: The sooner you learn to use a debugger, the better. It is an essential tool along with reading man pages. If you want to progress, you need to be able to this for yourself.

Comment: @Barmar I shrunk the problem down as much as i could. I only put the functions used for the first two options on the menu. It  reads the file perfectly fine, there are just some characters missing on the first line, but every other line after that is read perfectly.

Comment: You could leave out the menu function, that's not relevant, is it? Basically you're calling `submitAssignment`, `getAssignment`, and `displayAssignment`, right?

Comment: One purpose of preparing the [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is that you may find the problem yourself, in its making. When coding, always be prepared to set up test examples to work out a specific point. As the old adage says: don't give the man fish: teach him how to fish.

Comment: When creating the MCVE, please also add sets of sample input, current output and desired output.

Comment: Creating an MCVE is not only for us, so we don't have to read irrelevant code, but also for *your* sake. Trying to simplify your own program can often help you find the problem yourself. It will also make it much easier for you to [*debug*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your code.

Comment: @Barmar i'm literally just asking for help to fix my code, not for someone to tell me how to post a question. I put what i thought was necessary. Obviously i'm new to posting/programming so give me a break. I don't understand why you feel the need to comment if it isn't because you want to actually help me.

Comment: We're all volunteering our time to help people like you, don't give us a hard time when we ask you to make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: You misunderstood the advice, which was how to find the problem for yourself. This is not a debug-my-wall-of- code site, and that is why I finally downvoted the question.

Comment: @WeatherVane I tried to fix the problem myself. This has been a continuation of 2 previous assignments so it got confusing to me. If i thought i could find the problem myself, do you think i would've still posted this question? I think a lot of you forget that programming is not as easy for new people, so making a new example of it for this question would not have been as easy for me as it would've been for most of you.

Comment: Of course it is not easy, but in your next project you can make it easier on yourself, by using a strategy that builds the code step by testable step. At each stage test the response to typical inputs, absurd inputs, and corner cases. As for learning the debugger, start with a very simple `main` program to walk through.

Comment: @Barmar Having multiple people come at me because of how i posted my question isn't exactly helping me. I am obviously new to this so it would've made it way harder for me to have to make a new example of my code. I'm sure comments like the ones i've gotten makes others not want to post on here for fear of being ridiculed instead of being helped.

Comment: [Good read for new programmers](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @AlessaFaria You go to FAU?! I graduated from FAU Computer Science program last May! Try to take classes with Bullard, he was my favorite. GO OWLS!

Comment: @TormundGiantsbane Yes i do! I have Rajput right now but I have Bullard for Foundations next semester! Thank you for the article, i really appreciate it!

Comment: @AlessaFaria NP, [read this one too](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/). Good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`displayAssignment` is skipping over the first few characters of the assignment when it assigns `middleOfAssignment`. It's skipping the first `strlen(assignmentStruct->assignmentName) + strlen(assignmentStruct->studentName) + 2` characters.

It should just print `assignmentStruct->assignment`, there's no need for `middleOfAssignment`. The only reason for that code would be if `assignment` contained a copy of the assignment name and student name at the beginning, but it doesn't.

```
void displayAssignment(Assignment* assignmentStruct) {
    print(assignmentStruct->assignmentName, assignmentStruct->studentName);
    printf("%s \n", assignmentStruct->assignment);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I hope next time you keep in mind that not everyone on here knows as much as you might, and most would benefit from actual help, instead of comments that are cold and unnecessary (which probably push people away from programming and gives this community a bad reputation)

Comment: Like we said, the process of narrowing down the example will often help you identify the problem all by yourself.

Comment: I think you're failing to understand that it is not that easy for everyone.

Comment: Are you trying to become a programmer or not? Figuring stuff like this out is part of the process.

Comment: You were rude to me in the comments but answered my question anyways so i don't know why you had to be rude in the first place? How are you gonna "volunteer your time to help" and get nasty when people don't know things? Way to make people hate this community. Hard-headed people like you who think everyone is supposed to know just as much as them suck. At least when i become a programmer, i won't also become rude like you. I appreciate the help, really, and thanks for showing me how NOT to treat newcomers.

Comment: You're being obstinate to people who try to help people.

Comment: It wasn't be being obstinate. Me creating an entire new example would have taken me longer than just posting my code, **which already had the problem in it**, why is that such a hard thing to understand?